# Duplicity Error 5 & 22 in /proc/

Tags: fedora, backup, duplicity

I've been having some problems with duplicity to backup my root folder to an external drive. The code using is:

```
sudo duplicity full -v4 --no-encryption --exclude /mnt/ / file:///run/media/jjonker/backup-c/
```

which then returns:

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: none
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/1/clear_refs
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/1/clear_refs
Error [Errno 5] Input/output error getting delta for /proc/1/mem
Error [Errno 5] Input/output error getting delta for /proc/1/mem
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/1/task/1/clear_refs
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/1/task/1/clear_refs
Error [Errno 5] Input/output error getting delta for /proc/1/task/1/mem
Error [Errno 5] Input/output error getting delta for /proc/1/task/1/mem
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/10/clear_refs
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/10/clear_refs
Error accessing possibly locked file /proc/10/exe
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/10/task/10/clear_refs
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/10/task/10/clear_refs
Error accessing possibly locked file /proc/10/task/10/exe
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/1086/clear_refs
Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument getting delta for /proc/1086/clear_refs
Error [Errno 5] Input/output error getting delta for /proc/1086/mem
Error [Errno 5] Input/output error getting delta for /proc/1086/mem
Killed
```

I'm running duplicity version 0.7.17

Any clues how I can solve this? Can I simply exclude the /proc/ folder?

Thanks

Comment: `/proc` is a special folder, some kind of view that allow access to process info or kernel data. It should not be backuped or monitored.

Answer (score 2):

yes,

`--exclude /proc` should do the trick. the duplicity man page even mentions this explicitely [1]

> If you are backing up the root directory /, remember to --exclude /proc, or else duplicity will probably crash on the weird stuff in there.

..ede/duply.net

[1] http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html